# How to mount local directory to the image using docker in Windows?

Tags: docker, directory

I am trying to mount and access a local directory of my **windows-11** into a docker image, but it is not working I am using this docker [image](https://github.com/maxnth/LAREX_Docker) and sometimes it gave an **error -**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/Users/upadh/OneDrive/Desktop/news': mkdir /Users: file exists.
```

the directory which I am trying to mount - `C:\Users\upadh\OneDrive\Desktop\news` with docker image dir - `/home/books/`

I run this **command** but nothing happened (with lowercase c: and capital too)-

```
docker run -d --volume c:/Users/upadh/OneDrive/Desktop/news:/home/books/ 73c32f27444656166de509e70c9f02e8a9d671a29c1118fa6e6e3079291819de
```

I gave all the necessary folder permission too, How will I mount it so that I can use this directory in the image?

Comment: i have not tried this before but maybe you are declaring the volume with a lower case `c` and it should be declared with an uppercase `C`

Comment: I tried with an upper case `C:/` too!

Comment: and if you try: `docker run -d --volume c:/Users/upadh/OneDrive/Desktop/news:/home/books 73c32f27444656166de509e70c9f02e8a9d671a29c1118fa6e6e3079291819de
`, so without the trailing `/`

Comment: no help still no able to see the directory in the app!